# Scroll Inter fence of drop down with the parent scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jscrollpane

I have the below query :
I have form (form is too long, I have applied jscroll pane to the entire form), On that form i have used drop menu menu for selection (used bootstrap down down). The issue is when scroll is applied to the entire page, I cannot scroll the items inside the drop down menu.This has become blocker in my application.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have some code? to show us??

Comment: <div  data-role="page" id="pageID">
<div  class="scroll-pane RHSArea"><!--jscroll pane scroll-->
<form class="serviceRequestForms">
<label>Title</label>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btnDropDown btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-menu" data-toggle="dropdown"  ></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu menu dropDownUl" role="menu"></ul><!--bootstrap drop down-->
</div>
</form>
</div>

Comment: please create your current example on http://jsfiddle.net/ thank you

Comment: I have created my example : http://jsfiddle.net/deeptiaggarwal/c2Lwn461/4/ I want to scroll main page as well as content inside the drop down

Comment: This will solve the issue : scrollDropDown is the class of ul $('.scrollDropDown').bind("touchmove",function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      });